# How to create animated multiple line graph?

Tags: python, animation, graph, jupyter-notebook, line

I'm new at python and I'm trying to create an animated graph with multiple lines by following a youtube tutorial. I have managed to plot a single line but having trouble plotting a second and third line on the same graph. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
    
x1 = []
x2 = []
x3 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []
y3 = []
    
fig, ax =  plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 150)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
line1, = ax.plot(0, 0)
line2, = ax.plot(60, 0)
line3, = ax.plot(120, 0)
    
    
def animation_frames(i):
    x1.append(i*10)
    x2.append(i*10)
    x3.append(i*10)
    y1.append(i)
    y2.append(i)
    y3.append(i)
       
    line1.set_xdata(x1)
    line1.set_ydata(y1)
    line2.set_xdata(x2)
    line2.set_ydata(y2)
    line3.set_xdata(x3)
    line3.set_ydata(y3)
    return [line1, line2, line3]
    

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frames, frames=(0, 10, 0.1), interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code means all the line you have is on top of each other

```
x1.append(i*10)
x2.append(i*10)
x3.append(i*10)
```

Change it and see for yourself

```
x1.append(i*10)
x2.append(i*20)
x3.append(i*30)
```

The output I'm getting :
[image]